# How did Proto-Germanic "e" break into "ja" in Old Norse?

Tags: old-norse

How did Proto-Germanic "e" break into "ja" in Old Norse?
I can't realize it.
for instance helpaną hjalpa

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? How it developed, or how it's pronounced? It's a straightforward onglide, if you speak English you're already familiar with more of them than most.

Comment: How it developed

Comment: I don’t think anyone knows for sure, but the ‘default’ way to get there would be to have diphthongisation of /ɛ/ to /iɛ/, and then opening of /iɛ/ to /iæ/ and finally /ia/. All these developments are commonly attested – in fact, almost exactly that sequence of events is found in Eastern dialects of Finnish: long /eː/ diphthongised to /ie/ (in all of Finnish), then opened to /iæ ~ ia/ (depending on vowel harmony) in eastern dialects.